# Convert a 12hour System time to 24 hour and display in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I have used Calendar.getTime() method to get the device time. The time returned is Tue Feb 01 11:33:35 PST 2000".
Then SimpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getTime()) is returning 7:33 PM (to TIME_ONLY format) for the input value 19:33 (24 Hour format).

This is puzzling me. Later I have used getTimeInstance() to check the time returned by Calendar.getTime(). The value is :11:33:35 AM

I have set the timezone to SimpleDateFormat as device timezone.

Now i need your suggestion. Should i parse the time using DateFormat and return the value inspite of SimpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getTime()).

I understand that both Calendar.getTime() is returning device time and SimpleDateFormat.format() is using device timeone. That may be the reason for the 12 hour format. But why Calendar.getTime() is returning time in PST and why SimpleDateFormat.format() is converting it to GMT and displaying the same.

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:s  a");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have parsed the date to the required format.